# How to print scientific numbers

Tags: java, android

How to print scientific numbers instead of a normal numbers? I have very small number and it is shown to be 0.0

Comment: Not going to show any effort? Well then, neither will I.

Comment: Can you post the code you're using now?

Comment: Would a code help here? I just can't find which command would change number printing in Eclipse

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Many choices:

- [`DecimalFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html), or
- [`String#format()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29), or
- [`PrintStream#printf()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) (as in `System.out.printf(...)`).

Comment: You also can convert the number into a string using [String.format](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object...)) :
    String.format ("%e", yourNumber);

or your can print the number and format it in the same time:

    System.out.[printf](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object...)) ("%e", yourNumber);

Comment: you're welcome

P.S.: there's also PrintStream.printf and System.out is a PrintStream.

Comment: D'oh, you're right - `System.out` is a `PrintStream` not a `PrintWriter`, my bad. Fixed my answer, thank you again.